# Does Caitlyn's Ace in the Hole have a maximum range after use?

Tags: league-of-legends

I know that some champion's ults have a "leash" range to them after being used, like Nautilus' for instance.

But my question is, since Caitlyn's ult gives vision on it's target while channeling, is there any way to either:
 A) break the channel by out-ranging it
 B) Out-range the actual projectile once it's fired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **NO**.

Long answer: The mechanic of Ace in the hole is: If you have vision of the opponent you can use the skill, when the skill is used you WILL fire the shoot.

The only way is to some ally enter in front of the shoot and take the damage. OR you kill Caty BEFORE she fires at you.

> **Ace in the Hole** (Active): Caitlyn marks an enemy champion at a huge range and channels for 2 seconds to line up the perfect shot,
>   providing vision of the target for the duration. She then fires the
>   projectile to deal massive physical damage. Enemy champions can
>   intercept the bullet for their ally.

Comment: Probably the best answer to this question because of the lay-out.

Comment: Thanks, learned how to create a good lay-out for questions and answers from @Raven and the others in the chat.

Answer (score 3):

Once Caitlyn's ultimate goes off its impossible to stop it from hitting other than getting another champion/hero to block it from reaching you.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, once it locks in, it's coming for you! The way to dodge it is to have one of your allies with enough health to survive it to get in the path of her ultimate, and it will hit them instead of you! :)

Answer (score -1):

The Caitlyn ultimate (out of interceptions) can be dodged with Fizz's e, can be stopped by Sivir's shield, can be denied by Banshee, using Shaco's ultimate is other whay to dodge it, another important thing u can dodge it if u are fast enough to get far from Caitlyn while she's focusing for that 2seconds time and of course u can disable her while focusing!

Comment: Nocturne shield, Vladimir bloodbath, wukong by walking in line with the ult, using decoy and do a step forward (maybe pantheon passiv?)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question regarding her skill's range. There is also incorrect grammar and spelling, making it hard to read.